# Keras incompatible input dimensions when unrolling LSTM

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Why does the following code give `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_14: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1`? It works when I remove `unroll=True`, a param that I wouldn't expect to affect the LSTM's output dimension.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
  100,
  batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 17),
  unroll=True
))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I suppose it has to do with this:

```
In [9]: from keras.models import Sequential
   ...: from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
   ...: from keras import backend as K
   ...: def LSTM_output_dimensions(*args,**kwargs):
   ...:   model = Sequential()
   ...:   model.add(LSTM(
   ...:     *args,
   ...:     **kwargs
   ...:   ))
   ...:   return K.ndim(model.outputs[0])
   ...:

In [10]: LSTM_output_dimensions(50, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 17))
Out[10]: 2

In [11]: LSTM_output_dimensions(50, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 17),return_sequences=True)
Out[11]: 3

In [12]: LSTM_output_dimensions(50, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 17),unroll=True)
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: LSTM_output_dimensions(50, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 17),unroll=True,return_sequences=True)
Out[13]: 2
```

Comment: Which `Keras` version do you use?

Comment: keras 2.0.5 on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug in Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/7387) that occurs because `unroll=True` is not relevant for an input shape of `(1, x)`.